# Java selenium using xpath : NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium

Now I'm doing browser test with selenium(java).

However, there are some problems with xpath.
I tried below code.

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@onclick='addUserWf();return false;']")).click();
```

with web element

```
<button class="btn-etc btn-object-add" onclick="addUserWf();return false;">...</button>
```

Maybe you can refer, spring boot print :

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@onclick='addUserWf();return false;']"}
```

I can see above element(It means element displayed and visible), so I can't understand.

Add : I tried this, but result was same.

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn-etc btn-object-add']")).click();
```

**Someone knows this?**

Answer (score 2):

Try below xpath:

```
 webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@onclick=\"addUserWf();return false;\"]")).click();
```

or

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[starts-with(@onclick='addUserWf')]")).click();
```

And its always good practice to use webdriver wait before clicking on any button.

```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(XPATH)))
```